# Remove individual rows of a grid view only on the client side

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a drop down list. On changing the index of the dropdownlist , I populate an asp.net gridview.

I have a requirement where the user should be able to remove individual rows of the gridview on the screen . 
 At the end of each row, I intend to have a remove button. On clicking the button the row should
 disappear . But this should be only on the screen. There should be no changes done in the database.

I have my code below right now :

aspx

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblClient" runat="server" Text="Client :" CssClass="label" ForeColor="Black"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvMainLog" runat="server" Visible="true" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"AllowPaging="true">
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Instruction" HeaderText="Instruction" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProviderId" HeaderText="Id" />
                    </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <div>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditMin" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gvMainLog.DataSource = GetSetupUtility(1);
            gvMainLog.DataBind();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the GridView add the remove command like this

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Instruction" HeaderText="Instruction" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProviderId" HeaderText="Id" />
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="Remove"
            Text="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

In the action of the remove button use the DeleteRow method

```
void gvMainLog_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Remove")
    {
        var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
        gvMainLog.DeleteRow(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: hello.. I just want it to disapper from the screen. i do not want to remove it from the database...

Comment: @SqlSamurai the DeleteRow deletes the row from the Grid and the dataset but does not execute any DELETE on the DABABASE

Answer (score 0):

You need somthing like this:
Use TemplateField in gridview.

```
<script>
function deleteRow(rowId) {
    $("#" + rowId).remove();
}
</script>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id='<%# "myRow" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'> contents <img src="deleteImageUrl" onclick='<%# "deleteRow(\"myRow" + Container.DataItemIndex+"\")" %>'/> </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```